# Changing jLabel text when progressbar reaches some value

Tags: java, netbeans, text, progress-bar, jlabel

I'm doing a primitive splash screen. When the progressbar reaches 20% the jLabel text must change to "Wait...it's still loading".

How can I do that?

That's my code:

```
new Thread(){
        public void run(){
                for(int i=0; i<101; i++){                   
            try {
                Thread.sleep(40);
                jProgressBar1.setValue(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(Carregando.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
          }
        }
    }.start();
```

Where do I put the code `jLabel1.setText("Wait...it's still loading")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the following code:

```
new Thread(){
        public void run(){
                for(int i=0; i<101; i++){                   
            try {
                Thread.sleep(40);
                jProgressBar1.setValue(i);
                if(i==20){//for checking 20% 
                   jLabel1.setText("Wait...it's still loading");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(Carregando.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
          }
        }
    }.start();
```